# Plotting in R; cannot be coerced to double error

Tags: r, graphing

I am trying to plot a and b, each consisting of 7500 data points. However when 
I tried plot(x,y), I got the following error:

```
> plot(a[11],b[11])
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

Which is strange,because all values all whole numbers. 
What can I do?

Thank you.

Comment: this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to plot a vector from a list. Try subseting using `$` or `[[]]` instead.

Here's your problem:

```
a <- as.list(data.frame("x"=1:5,"y"=5:1))
b <- as.list(data.frame("x"=1:5,"y"=5:1))

plot(a[2],b[2]) ## recreates your error
```

Here's the solution:

```
plot(a$y, b$y) ## plots as expected subsetting by $
```

Alternatively, if you'd prefer to stick with numbers:

```
plot(a[[2]],b[[2]])
```

I would strongly recommend that you read the help page associated with this:

```
?'['
```